# libaacs for Apple Silicon

Tags: macos, ventura, vlc, blu-ray

I have the key.cfg file installed but the libaacs dynamic library appears to not be working. I'm assuming this is because it is Intel and not ARM.

I got the file here:

https://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/

Does anyone know how to get Blu-rays to play in VLC on Apple Silicon Macs?

Comment: The library file is compiled for Intel only so you need to get a version that has been recompiled for ARM or comiled for Universal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was to install libaacs from homebrew.

```
brew install libaacs
Open /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libaacs
Copy libaacs.0.dylib
Paste in /usr/local/lib
Symlink libaacs.0.dylib to libaacs.dylib
```